# Validation rule max requires at least 1 parameters

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with laravel 6 when I use sweetalert, please help me, and here I include the code

I have a problem with my laravel, I can't post data

One mistake said

Validation rule max requires at least 1 parameters.

Dan ini controller saya

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validasi = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'level' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max|20'
        ], [
            'name.required' => 'Nama lengkap harus di isi !',
            'username.required' => 'Username harus di isi !',
            'email.required' => 'Email harus di isi !',
            'level.required' => 'Level harus di isi !',
            'password.required' => 'Password harus di isi !'

        ]);

        $new_user = new \App\User();

        $new_user->name = $request->get('name');
        $new_user->username = $request->get('username');
        $new_user->email = $request->get('email');
        $new_user->level = $request->get('level');
        $new_user->password = \Hash::make($request->get('password'));

        if ($validasi->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('user.create')->withInput()->withErrors($validasi);
        }

        $new_user->save();

        Alert::success('Profile data successfully added ');

        return redirect()->route('user.index');
    }
```

Comment: You need to write `max:20` instead of `max|20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `password` validation 
you write it by mistake `max|20` you should edit it to `max:20`

```
$validasi = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'level' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:20'
        ], [
            'name.required' => 'Nama lengkap harus di isi !',
            'username.required' => 'Username harus di isi !',
            'email.required' => 'Email harus di isi !',
            'level.required' => 'Level harus di isi !',
            'password.required' => 'Password harus di isi !'

        ]);
```